# Solving $x^{100}− y^{100 }= 100!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, factoring

Please some hint on how to solve in the set of natural numbers
$$x^{100} − y^{100} = 100!$$
The question comes from the [Serbian Junior Mathematical Olympiad 2020](https://dms.rs/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/JSMO2020.pdf).

I have tried with Fermat`s theorem using $x^{100}=x^{101-1}$, same with $y$ and that $x$ is a multiple of $101$ and $y^{100}=1 \pmod {101}$

Comment: Please show your attempts.

Comment: For any $y \geq 0$, $x= \sqrt[100]{100!+y^{100}}$ is a solution... Or maybe you make some assumptions on who are $x$ and $y$ ?...

Comment: Shall $x,y$ be integers ?

Comment: In the set of natural numbers.

Comment: @Philip What have you tried ?

Comment: I have tried with Fermat`s theorem using x^100=x^101-1, same with y and that x is multiple of 101 and y=1mod101

Comment: @Philip do you mind putting your attempts along with the question. This will avoid downvotes!

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Admittedly the tag choices made by a new poster are often unreliable. But in my humble opinion the addition of the tag [tag:number-theory] comes with at least a strong inference if not an implicit assumption that the variables are integers :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Well, in the first version, there was also the tag "linear-algebra"...  Finding the real solutions of this equation is as much number-theory as finding the integer solutions is linear-algebra !

Comment: Point conceded, @TheSilverDoe :-)

Answer (score 7):

You have shown that a solution requires $x=101k$.  Therefore $$x^{100}-y^{100}\geq101^{100}-100^{100}\geq100\times100^{99}=100^{100}>100!$$

The first inequality follows from $(101k)^{100}-y^{100}$ taking its smallest positive value for fixed $k\in \mathbb{N}$ when $y=101k-1$ and $(101k)^{100}-(101k-1)^{100}$ being an increasing function in $k\in\mathbb{N}$ (and negative when $k=0$).

The second inequality follows from the binomial expansion of $(100+1)^{100}$.

The final inequality follows from $100>1,2,3,\cdots,99$.

Comment: How could I overlook this method with the difference of consecutive $100$ th powers (+1)

Comment: Since there is no solution for $0\le y\le 10^8$ , which I checked by brute force (which was of course a huge overkill , since limit $100$ would have already be sufficient), there cannot be integer solutions at all.

Comment: At least my routine showed that there is still no integer solution with $|y|\le 10^8$ , if we replace the exponent in $x^{100}$ by any other integer exceeding $1$.

Comment: @Peter As $100$ is even, an integer solution would yield a solution in the naturals, by taking absolute values.

Comment: @tkf This is not what I mean : $100\cdot 100^{99}=100^{100}$ is what I noticed after the comment of TheSilverDoe

Comment: @Peter Thanks yes of course $99+1=100$.  That is fixed now.  My comment was regarding your proof that there are no integer solutions.  I was saying that instead you could use $(-x)^{100}=x^{100}$.

Comment: @tkf It is clear that we can assume $x,y\ge 0$ WLOG, so we only have to consider non-negative solutions.

Comment: Perhapd you should add (in the case that $y=0$ is allowed as a natural number) that $y=0$ does not give a solution although this is obvious. But the argument with the differences only works if we rule out this case.

Comment: @Peter If $y=0$ then $x^{100}-y^{100}=x^{100}\geq x^{100}-(x-1)^{100}$.  Which bit of the argument does not hold?

Comment: The argument that the difference must exceed $100!$ making a solution impossible.This is the key argument to show that there cannot be integer solutions. And for small enough $x$ and $y=0$ , this particular argument does not work.

Comment: @Peter We know $x=101k$.  Do you want me to add that $k> 0$?

Comment: I think, this is best, everyone will easily notice why $k=0$ does not give a solution.

Comment: @Peter I made an edit - is this what you suggested?

Comment: Fine now, I hope the author will accept it.

Answer (score 2):

I have a clear solution. First, let's apply Fermat's little theorem and we have $ x ^ { 100 } , y ^ { 100 } \equiv 1 \pmod { 101 } $. Then we can use Wilson's theorem and get $ 100 ! \equiv - 1 \pmod { 101 } $. So, the left-hand side of the equation ($ x ^ { 100 } - y ^ { 100 } $) is a multiple of $ 101 $, but the right-hand side ($ 100 ! $) is not. Therefore, no solutions exist in the set of natural numbers.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Math.SE. It would be preferable to use MathJax for mathematical expressions. Check out math.stackexchange.com/help/notation to get started if you're unfamiliar with it.

Comment: Oh, okay thanks. I'm new to the site.

Comment: It's alright, we were all newbies at some point. Stick around long enough, and you will soon be the one giving friendly advice to newcomers.

Comment: The easier observation for showing that $ 100 ! $ is not a multiple of $ 101 $ is that $ 101 $ is a prime number (as you've already taken into account when using Fermat's little theorem) and thus it's not a multiple of any smaller natural numbers greater than $ 1 $, which are exactly all the multiplicands of $ \prod \limits _ { n = 2 } ^ { 100 } n = 100 ! $.

Comment: Yeah, but I happen to run into another problem. Well this proof is only valid for when x and y are NOT a multiple of 101 (rule of Fermat's Little theorem). I have a proof for when both x and y are a multiple of 101 but I'm still working on the case where only one of them is a multiple of 101.

Comment: Another tip for you as a newcomer: as multiple users may have put comments under a post, you may want to notify the user you are answering to. That can be done using an at sign followed by the username. Example: "@Mathology". Note that in each comment, the system doesn't allow you to notify more than a single user. Hope you have fun, learn a lot and help many others on MSE.